# Datepicker Range in Node RED

Tags: javascript, datepicker, nodes, node-red, date-range

I am currently using Node RED and want to make a Datepicker Range.
My goal is:

Use the two selected Dates from the two "Datepicker"-Nodes to display a certain time interval from my database.

Here is my Flow in JSON-Code:

(Be aware that you will need to **install "node-red-contrib-postgresql"** and **"node-red-dashboard"** beforhand)

```
[
    {
        "id": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "Flow 2",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": "",
        "env": []
    },
    {
        "id": "0623165a65c01c00",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "Processing Datepicker Output",
        "func": "if (msg.topic === \"Datepicker_Von\") {\n    // Hier verarbeiten Sie den Wert des ersten Datepicker-Node\n    var date1 = msg.payload;\n    // Führen Sie weitere Verarbeitungen für Datepicker1 durch\n} else if (msg.topic === \"Datepicker_Bis\") {\n    // Hier verarbeiten Sie den Wert des zweiten Datepicker-Node\n    var date2 = msg.payload;\n    // Führen Sie weitere Verarbeitungen für Datepicker2 durch\n}\n\nmsg.params = [date1, date2];\n\n\n/*\nvar date1 = msg.payload[0].Datepicker_Von;\nvar date2 = msg.payload[1].selectedDate;\n\nif(date1 && date2){\n    msg.payload = {date1, date2};\n    return msg;\n\n}\n*/",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 870,
        "y": 780,
        "wires": [
            [
                "5ca2e58ccda4292e",
                "5dbeae4a01d86c01"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "35a5189090d65418",
        "type": "postgresql",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "Abfrage_Kalender",
        "query": "SELECT wert, datum_m\nFROM alle.aggregatparameterwerte1min\nWHERE DATE(datum_m) BETWEEN $1 AND $2\n",
        "postgreSQLConfig": "7a4e4f0f64750523",
        "split": false,
        "rowsPerMsg": 1,
        "outputs": 1,
        "x": 1410,
        "y": 780,
        "wires": [
            [
                "c7ef1139c1942183"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "c7ef1139c1942183",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "debug 10",
        "active": false,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "false",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 1740,
        "y": 780,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "5ca2e58ccda4292e",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "debug 11",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "true",
        "targetType": "full",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 1200,
        "y": 940,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "1c2689ab7eb8477d",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "debug 12",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "false",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 780,
        "y": 480,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "5906020c8eecbd4b",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "debug 13",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "false",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 700,
        "y": 1040,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "95076555af56bb28",
        "type": "ui_date_picker",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "",
        "label": "Datepicker 2",
        "group": "c69e5a41.8b69a8",
        "order": 2,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "passthru": false,
        "topic": "Datepicker_Bis",
        "topicType": "str",
        "className": "",
        "x": 510,
        "y": 900,
        "wires": [
            [
                "5906020c8eecbd4b",
                "0623165a65c01c00"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "981a649d06af8b02",
        "type": "ui_date_picker",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "",
        "label": "Datepicker 1",
        "group": "c69e5a41.8b69a8",
        "order": 2,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "passthru": false,
        "topic": "Datepicker_Von",
        "topicType": "str",
        "className": "",
        "x": 510,
        "y": 620,
        "wires": [
            [
                "1c2689ab7eb8477d",
                "0623165a65c01c00"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "5dbeae4a01d86c01",
        "type": "ui_button",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "",
        "group": "c69e5a41.8b69a8",
        "order": 2,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "passthru": false,
        "label": "button",
        "tooltip": "",
        "color": "",
        "bgcolor": "",
        "className": "",
        "icon": "",
        "payload": "",
        "payloadType": "str",
        "topic": "Datepicker_Von",
        "topicType": "msg",
        "x": 1150,
        "y": 780,
        "wires": [
            [
                "35a5189090d65418"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "7a4e4f0f64750523",
        "type": "postgreSQLConfig",
        "name": "",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "hostFieldType": "str",
        "port": "5432",
        "portFieldType": "num",
        "database": "dme_lokal",
        "databaseFieldType": "str",
        "ssl": "false",
        "sslFieldType": "bool",
        "applicationName": "",
        "applicationNameType": "str",
        "max": "10",
        "maxFieldType": "num",
        "idle": "1000",
        "idleFieldType": "num",
        "connectionTimeout": "10000",
        "connectionTimeoutFieldType": "num",
        "user": "",
        "userFieldType": "str",
        "password": "",
        "passwordFieldType": "str"
    },
    {
        "id": "c69e5a41.8b69a8",
        "type": "ui_group",
        "name": "Default",
        "tab": "1013c4a0.9de38c",
        "order": 1,
        "disp": true,
        "width": "6",
        "collapse": false,
        "className": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "1013c4a0.9de38c",
        "type": "ui_tab",
        "name": "Home",
        "icon": "dashboard",
        "order": 1,
        "disabled": false,
        "hidden": false
    }
]
```

[image: Here a overview of my flow:]

As you can see I tried to connect the two "Datepicker"-Nodes with a "Function"-Node.
The problem is that the "Function"-Node doesen't recieve the two dates at the same time. The flow that is posted here is the latest variant that I tried and failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES it worked! But there is a small detail that needs to be paid attention to.
In the topic area of each "Datepicker"-Node you need to differentiate the topic with a "/"

Example:

Topic of Datepicker1: `datepicker/1`

Topic of Datepicker2: `datepicker/2`

**Also there needs to be taken note of that both topics of the datepickers need to be in format "string"**

Here is the config-Tab for the "Datepicker"-Node with the Name "Datepicker 1"
Write the exact same thing into the second datepicker but replace all "1" with "2"

[image: Datepicker 1]

Here the JSON-Code if other people want to try for them selfs :D

```
[
    {
        "id": "1c2689ab7eb8477d",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "debug 12",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "true",
        "targetType": "full",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 600,
        "y": 600,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "5906020c8eecbd4b",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "debug 13",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "true",
        "targetType": "full",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 580,
        "y": 980,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "95076555af56bb28",
        "type": "ui_date_picker",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "",
        "label": "Datepicker 2",
        "group": "c69e5a41.8b69a8",
        "order": 2,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "passthru": true,
        "topic": "datepicker/2",
        "topicType": "str",
        "className": "",
        "x": 290,
        "y": 840,
        "wires": [
            [
                "5906020c8eecbd4b",
                "e1839d533034eac0"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "981a649d06af8b02",
        "type": "ui_date_picker",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "",
        "label": "Datepicker 1",
        "group": "c69e5a41.8b69a8",
        "order": 1,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "passthru": false,
        "topic": "datepicker/1",
        "topicType": "str",
        "className": "",
        "x": 290,
        "y": 660,
        "wires": [
            [
                "1c2689ab7eb8477d",
                "e1839d533034eac0"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "e1839d533034eac0",
        "type": "join",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "Datum_Vereinen",
        "mode": "custom",
        "build": "object",
        "property": "payload",
        "propertyType": "msg",
        "key": "topic",
        "joiner": "\\n",
        "joinerType": "str",
        "accumulate": false,
        "timeout": "",
        "count": "2",
        "reduceRight": false,
        "reduceExp": "",
        "reduceInit": "",
        "reduceInitType": "",
        "reduceFixup": "",
        "x": 630,
        "y": 760,
        "wires": [
            [
                "39fa5e85975fab78"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "39fa5e85975fab78",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "df8b8a9806f4a546",
        "name": "debug 15",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "payload",
        "targetType": "msg",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 860,
        "y": 760,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "c69e5a41.8b69a8",
        "type": "ui_group",
        "name": "Default",
        "tab": "1013c4a0.9de38c",
        "order": 1,
        "disp": true,
        "width": "6",
        "collapse": false,
        "className": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "1013c4a0.9de38c",
        "type": "ui_tab",
        "name": "Home",
        "icon": "dashboard",
        "order": 1,
        "disabled": false,
        "hidden": false
    }
]
```

Thanks for helping me! :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the join node, place it before the function node and configure it to wait for 2 inputs before sending the joined result.

Comment: You should be able to configure different `topic` values for each date picker inputs

Comment: That doesen't work :(. It says : "Message missing key property 'msg.topic' - cannot add object". I tried to set the topics of both datepickers to "date". I tried to set them as a string and as a msg but both didnt work. 
In the "Join"-Node I set the value to msg.topic and that it should only send when two values have been given to it.

Comment: thanks for the help! It worked with the "Join"-Node after some things I tried :D